# Getting error Cannot read property 'viewport' of undefined in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, testing, automation, mocha.js, puppeteer

I am trying to emulate devices on the puppeteer, for that I written below code block in nodejs and mocha test function

```
it('Should launch a mobile window', async function () {
    const mobile = puppeteer.devices['iPhone X']
    await page.emulate(mobile)
    await page.goto('https://www.imperva.com')
    await page.waitFor(5000)

})
```

But after running the test, I am getting below error

```
  1) Device emulation
   Should launch a mobile window:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewport' of undefined
  at Page.emulate (node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:843:38)
  at Context.<anonymous> (tests\device.test.js:28:20)
  at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: List of supported devices is available here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/DeviceDescriptors.ts

Answer (score 1):

you haave not defined page

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone X'];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
})();
```

FOr your code :

```
it('Should launch a mobile window', async function () {
    const mobile = puppeteer.devices['iPhone X']
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulate(mobile)
    await page.goto('https://www.imperva.com')
    await page.waitFor(5000)

})
```